# How to delete the top bar in MFC?

Tags: mfc

I'm using MFC to create a windows GUI project,As the scrrencap,i want to delete the top menu(or called otherthing,i don't know),anyone can tell me how to make it,thanks very much!
[image]

Comment: You can try to subclass the CMFCRibbonBar class.

Comment: @VuVirt,can you explain more concertely?thanks.

Comment: @ starkshang you could examine the afxribbonbar header and cpp files to figure it out from there. There is a way to do it with RemoveAll(), you can check the explanation in my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

In CMainFrame::OnCreate after the lines:

```
m_wndRibbonBar.Create(this);  
m_wndRibbonBar.LoadFromResource(IDR_RIBBON);
```

add the following line:

```
m_wndRibbonBar.GetQuickAccessToolbar()->RemoveAll();
```

The above approach works in a new Office style MFC app.

Of course another way could be to subclass CMFCRibbonBar and add the call to

```
    GetQuickAccessToolbar()->RemoveAll();
```

at the end of LoadFromResource function.